# Is it possible to use Google Containers privately not in the Cloud?

Tags: docker, lxc, kubernetes, linux-containers, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm researching:

- **[Docker Container](https://www.docker.com/)**
- **[Google Containers](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/)**

The goal is to use something of these 2 on our own physical boxes with Linux in the enterprise for Dev/Prod. However, I've read that Google reimplemented LXC (Linux Containers) and use their own [**lmctfy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lmctfy) instead.

**Is it possible to use Google Containers on my Linux boxes without their cloud space?** 
Your experience is highly appreciated.

Comment: Err, what's the question? You need to be more specific.

Comment: @Adrian Mouat rephrased

Comment: What does "without their cloud space" mean? I'm pretty sure you'll find things a lot easier with Docker...

Comment: @Adrian Mouat it means, on the intranet enterprise-wide with firewall, not using Google Cloud space. By the way Google containers use Docker too. I'm just wondering why they rewrote LXC.

Comment: Google started using containers long before Docker was on the go. They contributed a lot to the development of LXC, which Docker then piggybacked on. I assume the point of lmctfy is you can run it on your own hardware, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but neither kubernetes (the framework on which Google Container Engine runs) nor docker require a particular cloud provider. AFAIK, you can use docker containers on any linux distro, and kubernetes supports a number of configurations for running on your own machines. See [kubernetes getting started guides](http://kubernetes.io/gettingstarted/) for details.

Comment: Yes, you got the question right. Thanks for the link, very helpful. And since Google's Kubernetes works on top of Docker, this proves it to be very promising.